# how to generate random numbers with conditons impose in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, random, conditional-statements

I would like to generate 500 different combination of a,b,and c meeting the following conditions

1. a+ b+ c = 1 and
2. a < b < c

here is a basic sample of generating random numbers, however, I need to generate it based on aforementioned conditions.

```
Coeff = data.frame(a=runif(500, min = 0, max = 1),
b=runif(500, min = 0, max = 1),
c=runif(500, min = 0, max = 1))
```

Comment: Do you care what the sampling distribution is? You can draw random numbers and then filter out combinations that don't meet the criteria

Comment: Not really- I don't care about the distribution. All I want is that the sample generated should meet the two criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```r
myrandom <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(runif(3*n), ncol=3)
  m <- cbind(m, rowSums(m)) # rowSums is efficient
  t(apply(m, 1, function(a) sort(a[1:3] / a[4])))
}
```

Demonstration:

```r
set.seed(2)
(m <- myrandom(5))
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.1099815 0.3287708 0.5612477
# [2,] 0.1206611 0.2231769 0.6561620
# [3,] 0.2645362 0.3509054 0.3845583
# [4,] 0.2057215 0.2213517 0.5729268
# [5,] 0.2134069 0.2896015 0.4969916
all(abs(rowSums(m) - 1) < 1e-8) # CONSTRAINT 1: a+b+c = 1
# [1] TRUE
all(apply(m, 1, diff) > 0)      # CONSTRAINT 2: a < b < c
# [1] TRUE
```

Note:

- my test for "sum to 1" is more than just `==1` because of IEEE-754 and [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), suggesting that any floating-point test should be an inequality vice a test for equality; if you test for `==1`, you will eventually find occurrences where it does not appear to be satisfied:

  ```r
  set.seed(2)
  m <- myrandom(1e5)
  head(which(rowSums(m) != 1))
  # [1]  73 109 199 266 367 488
  m[73,]
  # [1] 0.05290744 0.24824770 0.69884486
  sum(m[73,])
  # [1] 1
  sum(m[73,]) == 1
  # [1] FALSE
  abs(sum(m[73,]) - 1) < 1e-15
  # [1] TRUE
  max(abs(rowSums(m) - 1))
  # [1] 1.110223e-16
  ```

Comment: Yes, I was just testing the code and found that there were places where the condition==1 is not met. Is there a way around to cover this and create sample that would only meet defined conditions? ` head(which(rowSums(m) != 1))
[1] 218 366 435 463 500'

Comment: As I explained in the answer, "condition == 1" when using floating-point is a fundamentally flawed test. Really, I'm not just blowing smoke here. The R FAQ 7.31 exists for a reason, and frankly I believe it understates the principle of floating-point comparisons. Either perform a test of inequality (with some tolerance, as I demoed) or solve the IEEE-754 problem (and publish it!). The **largest** deviation I have in this sample is `1.110223e-16`, I'd think that was sufficient.

Comment: If you read about the [`.Machine`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/.Machine) special variable, it defines its `double.eps` component as *"the smallest positive floating-point number 'x' such that '1 + x != 1'"*. On my 64-bit win10 R-3.5.3, that's `2.220446e-16`. Interestingly, `max(abs(rowSums(m) - 1))` is `1.110223e-16`, but `(max(abs(rowSums(m) - 1)) + 1) == 1` is true ... so when you get that small, you really need different data structures and base operators.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans this really helps. I am trying to develop a rainfall runoff model and these coefficients are actually generated to pass it to an equation (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152506/how-to-fit-linear-regression-model-to-get-maximum-r-squaired-value-in-r). I want to retain the coefficient that give me the highest R-squared value. Any comment in there would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I learned a few new R function from you while solving my problem- Thank you.

Comment: (That's how I have been learning and continue to learn R, by reading other answers.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that ANY distribution law (uniform, gaussian, exponential, ...) will produce numbers `a`, `b` and `c` meeting your condition as soon as you normalize and sort them, so there should be some domain knowledge to prefer one over the other.

As an alternative, I would propose to use [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) which produce numbers naturally satisfying your first condition: a+b+c=1. It was applied to rainfall modelling as well, I believe (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02962.pdf)

```
library(MCMCpack)
abc <- rdirichlet(n, c(1,1,1))
sum(abc) # should output n
```

You could vary power law values to shape the data, and, of course, sort them to satisfy your second condition. For many cases it is easy to argue about your model behavior if it uses Dirichlet (Dirichlet being prior for multinomial in Bayes approach, f.e.)

Comment: Thank you for the additional insights. in my situation, I am not really concerned with using a particular distribution (any distribution would work)- I am generating some number (which in my case is uniform). I am trying to solve a problem mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152506/how-to-fit-linear-regression-model-to-get-maximum-r-squared-value-in-r which honestly, I am still struggling to get it done. Let me know if you have any suggestions for attacking that problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @Hydrologist `I am generating some number (which in my case is uniform)`. No, they are not uniform, that is the problem, they have weird distribution of U_i/Sum(U_i), as far as I know there is no name and no properties for it. Dirichlet, from the other hand, is mentioned in each and every book on probability/statistcs. I'll take a look at your question