# Generating randomly a vector of integers that sum up to N with a given vector of probabilities in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to randomly generate vectors that have the following properties:

1) contains only integers.
2) the integers sum up to a fixed number.
3) the value of the integer in each position of the vector should be determined by probabilities given by a known vector.

Specifically, I am working with a gridded population dataset, and for each grid I have the share of population of the country living there. I also have a count variable that records how many members of parliament are from each grid (using geocoded birthplace). To evaluate how even or uneven the actual distribution of members of parliament is with respect to population, I need a series of 'mock count variables' that simulate distributions of members of parliaments as if they were roughly proportional to the distribution of the population.

Using the answer to another thread, I have been able to generate a random number of positive integers, given the number of grids and the number of MPs. However, I have no idea of how to assign MPs to a specific element of the vector with probabilities given by a vector of the same length. That is, in this way, each element of the vector is equally likely to get an MP, but what I want is that more populous grids should be more likely to get a higher number of MPs.

Hope this makes sense.

````r
rand_vect <- function(N, M, sd = 1, pos.only = TRUE) {
  vec <- rnorm(N, M/N, sd)
  if (abs(sum(vec)) < 0.01) vec <- vec + 1
  vec <- round(vec / sum(vec) * M)
  deviation <- M - sum(vec)
  for (. in seq_len(abs(deviation))) {
    vec[i] <- vec[i <- sample(N, 1)] + sign(deviation)
  }
  if (pos.only) while (any(vec < 0)) {
    negs <- vec < 0
    pos  <- vec > 0
    vec[negs][i] <- vec[negs][i <- sample(sum(negs), 1)] + 1
    vec[pos][i]  <- vec[pos ][i <- sample(sum(pos ), 1)] - 1
  }
  vec
}

rand_vect(gridnumber, MPnumber)

```r
````

Comment: (1) Integers only, np. (2) Fixed sum? Sample all but last number, subtract from the req'd sum. (3) Probs? Complicates #2, but possible. Given #2 and #3, it sounds like *random sampling until conditions met* is in order, which implies you may not get a valid response (in a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: Related (but not a perfect dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/q/57153619

Comment: `sample` has a `probs` argument... If you have `nmp` MPs to assign to positions in vector `x`, with larger `x` values being more likely, `sample(seq_along(x), size = nmp, prob = x, replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Gregor I tried that, I get a vector of size MPnumber, but how do I get a frequencies vector of size gridnumber?

Comment: The vector of size `MPnumber` is the district each MP is assigned to. Call that `mp_assignments`, and `table(factor(mp_assignments, levels = 1:gridnumber))` gets you the number of MPs in each. (assuming `gridnumber` is the maximum grid number. The `factor()` is needed in case some grids have 0 MPs)

Comment: @Gregor fantastic, sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it

```
rand_vect <- function(N, M, sd = 1, pos.only = TRUE,prob) {
  vec <- rbinom(N,1,prob)
  deviation <- M - sum(vec)
  for (. in seq_len(abs(deviation))) {
    vec[i] <- vec[i <- sample(N, 1,replace=TRUE,prob)] + sign(deviation)
  }
  if (pos.only) while (any(vec < 0)) {
    negs <- vec < 0
    pos  <- vec > 0
    vec[negs][i] <- vec[negs][i <- sample(sum(negs), 1)] + 1
    vec[pos][i]  <- vec[pos ][i <- sample(sum(pos ), 1)] - 1
  }
  vec
}
```